# Ayuda con subconsulta select Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Hola tengo una consulta a una funcion de SQL Server y necesito que en esa misma consulta me muestre campos de una tabla. Lo hice asi pero me muestra error. Ademas me subraya el query en rojo y aparece un mensaje que dice:
Se ha especificado un numero insuficiente de argumentos para el procedimiento o funcion funcion1

```
Select * from dbo.funcion1('A','2014-07-01','2014-07-01','2018-04-30',0,1, (Select campo1, campo2 from tabla where Cod_user='101'), '101',0) Order by Cod_lin
```

Error:

> Mens. 116, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 8
>       Sólo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección cuando la subconsulta no se especifica con EXISTS.
>       Mens. 313, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 8
>       Se proporcionó un número insuficiente de argumentos para el procedimiento o la función funcion1

Comment: Ayudaría a darte una buena respuesta si compartes el código de `funcion1`, por favor, edita la respuesta y agrega el mismo. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata con un top 1

```
Select * 
from dbo.funcion1 ('A','2014-07-01','2014-07-01','2018-04-30',0,1, 
(  Select top 1 campo1
   from tabla where Cod_user='101' ), 
(  Select top 1 campo2
   from tabla where Cod_user='101' ),'101',0) 
Order by Cod_lin
```

Ya que la subconsulta te está retornando más de un valor, la función no lo permite a menos que hagas join con la misma

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que buscaba